# Срабатывает только часть функции

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Прописал себе функцию на проверку занятости EMAIL. Функция AJAX, при несоответствии срабатывает PHP код, на запись в БД. При соответствии выводит всплывающее окно браузера, которое говорит о занятости.

```
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--Подключаем библиотеку-->

    <script>
        function funcBefore () {
            $("#info").text ("Заполните все поля регистрации");
        }

        $(document).ready (function () {
            $("#done").bind("click", function () {
                $.ajax ({
                    url: "checkEmail.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({ email: $("#email").val()}),
                    dataType: "html",
                    beforeSend: funcBefore,
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data == "Fail")
                            alert("Такой Email уже существует, попробуйте войти");
                        else
                            $("#info"). text ("Успешно");
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

Так же имеется вот такой код, где указывается условие

```
<?php
// Предворительно подключиться к базе и создать выборку по EMAIL на соответсвие
$sql = "SELECT Email FROM users";

sleep(1); //Пауза в 1 секунду

if ($_POST['email'] == $sql)
    echo "Fail";
else    
    header ("Location:index.php");
```

Но по факту срабатывает только эта часть кода, при нажатии на кнопку "Отправить", появляется на секунду, и выдаёт ошибку уникальности "EMAIL" в php.

```
            function funcBefore () {
            $("#info").text ("Заполните все поля регистрации");
        }
```

Задумка заключается в проверке занятости без перезагрузки формы.

Comment: html - ? *(6 символов нужно...)*

Comment: ради одной функции цеплять скриптище JQuery на 4к строк, через пять минут на вашем сайте у пользователя сядет телефон. И грузиться будет как госуслуги пятнадцать минут

Comment: а зачем делаете header ("Location:index.php")?

Answer (score 2):

```
        $("#done").click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.ajax ({
            ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

        $(document).ready (function () {


            if(!$("#email").val()) {
                funcBefore();    
            }              

            $("#done").on("click", function (e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax ({
                    url: "checkEmail.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: ({ email: $("#email").val()}),
                    dataType: "json",
                    //beforeSend: funcBefore, Зачем это тут?
                    success: function (data) {
                        if(data['fail'])
                            alert("Такой Email уже существует, попробуйте войти");
                        else
                            $("#info"). text ("Успешно");
                    }
                });
            });
        })
    </script>
```

И далее PHP

```
   <?php
   ....

   exit(json_encode(['fail'=>true]));
```